# tinymce setContent removes new lines

Tags: tinymce

If I have content preloaded in textarea then I have new lines converted to "br" tags.

But if I try to set content dynamically (not pasting) to tinymce textarea by using its setContent function new lines are missing.

I use v.3.4.7, tried v.3.5.6 (the latest by far) and it removes new lines even on page loading.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    tinyMCE.init({
        mode: "textareas",
        editor_selector: "EmailBody",
        theme: "advanced",
        language: "en",
        charLimit: 10,
        plugins: "table,advhr,advlink,insertdatetime,preview,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality",
        theme_advanced_buttons1_add: "fontselect,fontsizeselect",
        theme_advanced_buttons2_add: "separator,insertdate,inserttime,preview,zoom,separator,forecolor,backcolor",
        theme_advanced_buttons2_add_before: "pastetext,pasteword,separator",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add_before: "tablecontrols,separator",
        theme_advanced_buttons3_add: "advhr,separator,ltr,rtl,separator",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        theme_advanced_statusbar_location: "bottom",
        plugi2n_insertdate_dateFormat: "%Y-%m-%d",
        plugi2n_insertdate_timeFormat: "%H:%M:%S",
        paste_use_dialog: false,
        theme_advanced_resizing: false,
        theme_advanced_resize_horizontal: true,
        paste_auto_cleanup_on_paste: true,
        paste_convert_headers_to_strong: false,
        paste_remove_spans: true,
        width: "100%",
        paste_remove_styles: true,
        valid_elements: "a[href|target=_blank],strong/b,div[align],p,br,i,u",
        content_css: "/css/tinymce_bigger_default_font.css",
        forced_root_block: false,
        force_br_newlines: true,
        force_p_newlines: false,
        apply_source_formatting: false,
        remove_linebreaks: false,
        convert_newlines_to_brs: true
    });
</script>

function Click()
{
    var text = document.getElementById("preText").innerText;
    tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(text);
}

<pre id="preText">Text

Text
</pre>
```

The result must be as follows:

```
Text

Text
```

But instead I get:

```
TextText
```

Comment: what is your question? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: sorry, jsut edited question, expected result is at the bottom

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How to replace new lines to break lines on initial content set:

`convert_newlines_to_brs` and `remove_linebreaks` parameters have been removed from tinymce (check your tinymce source code).

To restore `convert_newlines_to_brs` functionality use this code (it was taken from previous version of tinymce):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    setup : function(ed) {
        ed.onBeforeSetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
            if (o.initial) {
                o.content = o.content.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Using 4.2 I had to tweak this a bit but this answer put me on the right track.
tinymce.init({setup: function (editor) {editor.on('BeforeSetContent', function (contentEvent) {contentEvent.content = contentEvent.content.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');})}});

Comment: Patrick Graham's tweak listed in his comment above worked for me. Thanks Patrick! I've been working at this problem for two days and none of the little fixes like 'remove_linebreaks' would work for me.

Comment: Note for others looking at this: you have to have `forced_root_block: false` for this to work (which is set as such in the example, but it's a little buried)

Answer (score 4):

See my solution for this. I have created a tinymce fiddle: http://fiddle.tinymce.com/vTbaab

Comment: exactly! replacing new lines to <br>s is an acceptable solution for me

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to add

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        remove_linebreaks : false
});
```

This is nicely documented in their [help](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3aremove_linebreaks).

Answer (score 0):

I tried many other things to try to get this to work. It stemmed from the original developer not properly declaring the post type.

BEFORE:

```
'supports' => array('title','slug'),
```

AFTER:

```
'supports' => array('title','slug','editor'),
```